# Transferring array to next page

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I found some similar problems here, but none of them does really fit to my problem.

I want to create an array consisting of entries from my database. My code looks like that:

```
<?php
  include ("../script/db_connect.php");

  $select_questions = 'select * from users ';

  if (isset($_POST["own"]) && $_POST["own"] == "No") {
    $select_questions .= 'where creator != '
                       . $_SESSION["id"];
  }

  $select_questions .= ' limit ' 
                     . $number;

  $questions_result = mysqli_query($con, $select_questions);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions_result)) {
    $questions[] = $row;
  }

  $_SESSION["questions"] = $questions;

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

After that, I want to create an array, which will later be saved as a $_SESSION variable. To test my code, there is another page, where I want to echo my array. On the other page, I use the following php code:

```
<?php echo var_dump($_SESSION["questions"]); ?>
```

I tried different versions, but it still does not really work. I'm pretty new to PHP, so any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to **start session** by adding this line at the top of your **2** scripts :

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Of course, start session is in there, I just wanted to show the relevant code

Comment: you can place this line at the top of your HTML file (between <?php tag)

Comment: Seriously, there is nothing special. Just the session start, necessary info (charset, CSS) and my php include

Comment: Do the `session_start` is present on BOTH pages ? your HTML file and the file who do your <?php echo var_dump($_SESSION["questions"]); ?> ?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure